# Rearrangement property of diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

Is it true that for a diagonal matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, the following property holds:
$$
A^\top B A = A^\top A B,
$$
where in essence I am asking this: ***Can diagonal matrices be rearranged in matrix multiplications*** (we know this is not true in general from the basic laws of linear algebra)? The motivation for knowing this is that it helps to simplify the analysis of machine learning algorithms that uses singular/eigen value decomposition. Thanks.

Comment: For the second equality, the dimensions of the LHS is $1\times 1$, while the dimensions of the RHS is $n\times n$.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should be true. Orthogonal matrices are defined to be invertible and square, so this is equivalent to claiming that $A^TBA=B$. Those two expressions are similar matrices, but of course they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: $A$ is $n\times p$ and $B$ is $n\times n$. Unless $n=p$, the product $AB$ is illegitimate. Also, what do you mean by an $n\times p$ orthogonal matrix? Orthogonal matrices by definition are square matrices, but your $A$ is not (again, unless $n=p$). If you mean a matrix with orthonormal columns or orthonormal rows, please state that clearly.

Comment: Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and since $B=B^T$, the left side, we get 
$$
A^T BA = (BA)^T A.
$$
Assume $A=A^T$, the right side, we get
$$
A^TAB = A(BA)^T
$$
Since matrices are not commutative, even if the assumption of $A=A^T$ holds, we can't guarantee the equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. If we let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\ 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{ and }\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix},$$
then
$$A^\top AB = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{while} \quad A^\top B A = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$